# Maths behind red/blue-shifting

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reference-frames, velocity, doppler-effect, redshift

I watched this video of silly science facts, on of which stated "you can avoid red lights by travelling at around 114,000,000mph (51,000,000m/s) because the red light would be blue shited enough that it would appear green". So if we ignore the physical impossibility of travelling that fast on earth, is this true? I have a decent level of physics knowledge and I understand the concepts of red and blue shifting due to apparent velocity between the source and the observer. My questing is regarding the maths behind this statement, how would you prove or disprove this? And how would you get that specific number? It the formula behind red and blue shifting that I am not familiar with.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Relativistic_longitudinal_Doppler_effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical physical problem. But I don't see any problem in taking the luxury of answering the question. So, consider a relativistic inertial frame $S$ (the semaphore) at rest, and another relativistic frame $S'$ (our car) moving in the $x+$ direction with a velocity $v$. In $t = t' = 0$ the car meets the semaphore. We can apply the simplified Lorentz transformations for 1D motion, specially to convert a time interval from $S'$ to $S$. We have that:

$$\Delta t = \gamma (\Delta t' + \frac{v}{c^2} \Delta x') $$

The wave moves perpendicular to the movement axis, i. e. in the y axis. To convert the frequencies we must convert the time between two wave ‘ticks’ from $S'$ to $S$; so we have to account the effect of:

- Time shifting due to the shift itself given by relativity (time dilation due to Lorentz transformation).
- Time shifting due to the distance traveled by the car between two ticks.

Consider two events on $S'$, E1 = ‘first tick arrives’ and E2 = ‘second tick arrives’. Since in this frame it holds that $\Delta x' = 0$, then $\Delta t = \gamma \Delta t'$, where $\Delta t$ and $\Delta t'$ are the time between the two events measured from $S$ and $S'$ respectively. Now, between ticks, the car covered a distance (in S) of $v \Delta t$, and since the speed of the wave is $c$, to convert between periods in different frames we finally arrive at:

$$T = \Delta t - \frac{v \Delta t}{c} = \Delta t (1 - \frac{v}{c}) = \gamma \Delta t' (1 - \frac{v}{c}) = \gamma T' (1 - \frac{v}{c}) = T' \frac{1- \frac{v}{c}}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = T' \sqrt{\frac{1 - \frac{v}{c}}{1 + \frac{v}{c}}}$$

So:

$$ f' = f \sqrt{\frac{1 + \frac{v}{c}}{1 - \frac{v}{c}}}$$

Now, replace with $f = 450 THz$ (red frequency) and $f' = 550 THz$ (green frequency). Then, you would need to go with $v = 0.198c$ (c = speed of light) to see a green light from your car. However, the approach is absurd: first because it's impossible to go at such speed with a car and second because the cops don't care about these things and you'll be fined anyway.